# Launch ec2 using cloudformation which should use launch template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a ec2 instance using the launch template : 
So I have created a launch template with below data.

LaunchTemplateVerybasic:
[image: img1]

When I am trying to run a cloud formation template like below :

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  TestTemplate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateSpecification:
          LaunchTemplateId: lt-00d9f13eea240e524
          LaunchTemplateName: Testtemplate
          Version: '1'
```

I get this error:

> Encountered unsupported property LaunchTemplateSpecification, whereas
>   in designer it shows that instance can be created.

What is that I am missing? I checked the documentation and this is a property supported by AWS::EC2::instance..

Let me know if there is something I am missing in understanding and in yaml

Answer (score 2):

Since the EC2 is not being launched from the launch template via auto-scaling group, rather its via a resource definition, you need first to remove the and have the config as follows

```
  HostA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: !Ref HostALaunchTemplate
        Version: !GetAtt HostALaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
```

**Launch Template example**

When launching a launch template via auto-scaling group, usually there is no need to specify a network interface within the launch template because the auto-scaling group will take care of it.

Inside your launch template, **remove** the SecurityGroupIds at the LaunchTemplateData

```
  HostALaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: HostALaunchTemplate
      LaunchTemplateData:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !ImportValue MyASG
```

And **add** security group via network interface like so

```
  HostALaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: HostALaunchTemplate
        NetworkInterfaces:
          - DeviceIndex: 0
            Groups:
              - !ImportValue MyASG
            SubnetId: !ImportValue MySubnet
```

Answer (score 1):

The [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/)
catches this with:

`E3002 Invalid Property Resources/TestTemplate/Properties/LaunchTemplate/LaunchTemplateSpecification
template.yaml:7:9`

Try removing `LaunchTemplateSpecification`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  TestTemplate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: lt-00d9f13eea240e524
        LaunchTemplateName: Testtemplate
        Version: '1'
```

[`AWS::EC2::Instance.LaunchTemplate` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance-launchtemplatespecification.html)

Comment: got few errors from the template you suggested to use-
1.I should use exactly one (either templateId or name) , after fixing that , I got below error. 2."The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: Unsupported; Request ID: 11e03337-f295-4a75-b05c-5e1109b94686)"

AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  TestTemplate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: lt-00d9f13eea240e524
        Version: '1'

Comment: Does a LaunchTemplate with the ID `lt-00d9f13eea240e524` exist in the same account and region as your CloudFormation stack?

Comment: Yes same region

Comment: Which region are you deploying this template? `a1.medium` is not currently available in `us-gov-east-1`, `us-gov-west-1`, `eu-north-1`, `eu-west-3`, `eu-west-2`, `ap-northeast-3`, `ap-northeast-2`, `sa-east-1`, `ca-central-1`, `us-west-1`, `cn-north-1`, and `cn-northwest-1`

Comment: us-east-1 , which is having a1.medium